# C# How to Enumerate Specific Field of a Struct in a List<Struct> for use in ListBox Data Source

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, dictionary, listbox

**Updated code with answer is at the bottom**

---

I am building a system which stores client data in a SQLite db.

The data is being stored in instances of the following struct:

```
    public struct ClientData
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public string Email;
        public string Tel;
    }
```

A ClientData struct is created for each client and added to a list:

```
    private static void PopulateClients()
    {
        List<ClientData> tempClients = new List<ClientData>();

        string sql = "select * from clients;";
        SQLiteConnection mydb = OpenDBConnection(); 
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, mydb);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string tclientID = reader["id"].ToString();
            int clientID = Int32.Parse(tclientID);
            string clientName = reader["name"].ToString();
            string clientEmail = reader["email"].ToString();
            string clientTel = reader["tel"].ToString();

            ClientData cd = new ClientData();

            cd.ID = clientID;
            cd.Name = clientName;
            cd.Email = clientEmail;
            cd.Tel = clientTel;

            clientList.Add(cd);

            // MessageBox.Show(clientList[0].Name);
        }
        mydb.Close();
    }
```

I now wish to display the client's names in a listbox. I was able to achieve this by added all the client names to a separate list (clientNames), but I want all the client's data to be accessible here (so that different info can be displayed on client selection).

However, when calling this:

```
listboxClients.DataSource = Program.clientList;
```

My listbox displays the following:

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Program+ClientData
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to assign the list of client names to the listbox DataSource directly from List< ClientData > ? This way I can easily get the rest of the details for display by matchng up the client name (or ID).

Would really appreciate any advice on this.
Thank you

---

**UPDATE**

Created ClientData as a class instead of a struct:

```
public class ClientData
{
    // Ctor
    public ClientData(int id, string name, string email, string tel)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Tel = tel;
    }


    // Gets
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
}
```

New ClientData call:

```
        string tclientID = reader["id"].ToString();
        int clientID = Int32.Parse(tclientID);
        string clientName = reader["name"].ToString();
        string clientEmail = reader["email"].ToString();
        string clientTel = reader["tel"].ToString();

        ClientData cd = new ClientData(clientID, clientName, clientEmail, clientEmail);

        clientList.Add(cd);
```

Configuring the listbox:

```
        listboxClients.DisplayMember = "Name";
        listboxClients.DataSource = Program.clientList;
```

Comment: `listboxClients.DataSource = clientList` also you have this delcared `List<ClientData> tempClients = new List<ClientData>();` but you never use it..  you need to look at the following and pay attention to the order
`listBox.DataSource = clientList;
listBox.DataTextField = "Name";
listBox.DataValueField = "Name";
listBox.DataBind();`

Comment: @MethodMan, I am trying to use this code, but no matter what I Do I can't seem to use DataTextField on my listbox ... I have "using system.web.ui.webcontrols" and the code runs fine but as soon as I try using DataTextField I get a (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Not quite sure what is happening there ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ryan correctly mentioned, you need to use [DisplayMember Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx). But note that all data binding scenarios work only with properties, and your `struct` contains only fields. Also note that in data binding scenarios there is absolutely no benefit of using `struct`s - in fact, it involves a lot of boxing, so it's much better to use `class` instead.

So, in your case something like this should work:

```
public class ClientData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
listboxClients.DisplayMember = "Name";
listboxClients.DataSource = Program.clientList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `DisplayMember` property on the ListBox to whatever String property you want to display for each item within the List?

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx for details.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set DisplayMember:

```
listboxClients.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

and i think your line "cd.Name = client;" is wrong, it should be

```
cd.Name = clientName;
```